# How to make np.where work for float datatype

Tags: numpy

```
a=np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5])
np.where(a < 2)
```

I got (array([0, 1], dtype=int64),). How can I get array([0.5, 1.5])?

Comment: `a[a < 2]`, no need for `np.where`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.

`a < 2` gives `array([True, True, False])`, as it tests the condition element-wise.

`np.where(a < 2)` gives you **the indices where the result of `a < 2` is true.** It's true in the first and second elements, so it gives you the array of indices `[0, 1]`.

You *could* use those indices to then index the array:

```py
a[np.where(a < 2)]
```

However, like @Psidom says, this is unnecessary, as you can just index the array directly using

```py
a[a < 2]
```

and this would be the most pythonic way.